# Find the line that forms by two intersecting planes

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find the line that forms by the two intersecting planes:

$$x+y+3z+6=0$$
$$2x+y-2z-10=0$$

I get that $-y-8z-22=0$. I tried taking two points that satisfy this equation, and get the vector between them. But this apparently is not the line.

What am I doing wrong and how should I go about it?

Comment: The single equation you have is the equation of a plane - it does not constrain $x$. But to satisfy both the original equations choosing a value of $z$ tells you the value of $y$ and substituting back gives you the value of $x$ - you then have a line parametrised by the value of $z$ - i.e. the set of points $(x(z), y(z), z)$ which lie on both the original planes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x+y+3z+6=0$$
$$2x+y-2z-10=0$$

We set them equal to one another: $$x+y+3z+6=2x+y-2z-10 = 0 \iff x - 5z -16=0$$

Or: $x-5z=16 \iff x = 5z+16$

The resulting line puts $x=f(z) = 5z + 16$.

Answer (score 1):

The line is formed by the two intersecting planes so it's on both the planes.
This implies that the supposed line is perpendicular to the normals of both planes.
Thus assuming the direction ratios of the required line to be l,m and n respectively.
For the first plane equation:

1. l*1 + m*1 +n*3 = 0
2. For the second plane equation:
       l*2 + m*1 -n*2 = 0

   3. Now you can solve this two and get express two variables in terms of the third. Using this you have the direction ratios for the line.
   4. Now get a point which is on both the planes, and use the direction ratios obtained to write a line equation.

---

Comment: Sorry! I am not comfortable using this forum and I don't have any idea how to post this answer in a better way, so that it's easier to understand.